# Windows 10 won't boot - stuck on icon and rotating dots

Tags: windows-10, boot, recovery

Had an abnormal shut down the other night. PC won't boot.

No error messages, just gets stuck at the Windows icon nd circling dots.

I created aWindows 10 Media recovery thumb drive and booted with that. (It takes about 30 minutes to get to the "install windows" screen.

At this point I choose "Repair Windows"

After another 30 minutes, I get the "Troubleshooting" screen.

Startup Repair didn't fix or find anything.

System Restore couldn't find a restore point.

I got command prompt to open and did a bootrec /ScanOS and it found my System drive (usually my C: drive but in this recovery mode it's the G: drive)

I can see my files on the G: drive so I at least know the drive is "working" and can read data.

I've run `chkdsk /f /r /x`

This completed.

I then fan `SFC /SCANNOW`

That found no issues.

I rebooted.

Still stuck at the Windows icon with the circling dots.

What else can I do?

Comment: A better place to get help with this is https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance Be prepared that they will ask for boring technical details - which exactly is the Win10 version, PC model, 3rd party software and hardware installed - all that may be useful to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had created the Windows 10 Media Tool to boot from USB but kept running into super slow problems.

I eventually went into the BIOS and enabled USB boot for "Legacy Only"

This made booting from the USB much faster. And once I made it to the Windows Recovery Troubleshoot screen I clicked on "Startup Repair"

(I had tried this before and nothing happened)

But, I ran it this time and it ran fast, and fixed the problem and booting me into Windows.

I think the PC shut down during the middle of an update and that's what caused the problem.